# Fancytree selenium click event

Tags: java, selenium, junit, fancytree

We are testing a web application using selenium and are trying to simulate the fancy tree expand event using the following

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tree']/ul/li/span/span[@class='fancytree-expander']")).click();
```

The fancytree looks like this in the jsp

```
<div id="tree"></div>
```

The js code looks like this

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    extensions: ["filter"],
    filter: {
        autoApply: true, // Re-apply last filter if lazy data is loaded
        counter: false, // Show a badge with number of matching child nodes near parent icons
        hideExpandedCounter: true, // Hide counter badge, when parent is expanded
        mode: "hide"  // "dimm": Grayout unmatched nodes, "hide": remove unmatched nodes
      },        
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 3,
    quicksearch: true,
    source: {
        url: ...
    },


    lazyLoad: function(event, data) {
        ...
    },

    loadError: loadError,

    collapse: function(event, data) {
    }
 });
```

Can you let us know how can we simulate a fancy tree event click?

Comment: What happens now, any errors? Thanks.

Comment: can you add sample public site with the same case, and sample code which you are trying to run, error if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can execute any javascript code that you want in Selenium.

```
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.ExecuteScript("[your fire event javascript code]");
```

Answer (score 0):

The tree nodes are probably loaded via an Ajax request, so you have to wait until  the nodes are rendered. For example using a timeout or trigger something in the fancytree 'init' event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
tree = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,".//*[@id='left']/ul/li[3]/span/span[1]"))))

ActionChains(driver).click(tree).perform()
```